# Selenium WebDriverJS Using in Browser

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#In_the_Browser

Where I can get javascript file "webdriver.js" from

So I can test and use it. Has anyone have done it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`webdriver.js` can be built from the selenium sources. You need `java` and `svn` to take the following steps:

1. Get the selenium sources:

   `svn checkout http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ selenium-read-only`
2. Change to `trunk`:

   `cd selenium-read-only/trunk`
3. Build `webdriver.js`:

   `./go webdriverjs`

   This step generates a single javascript file in `build/javascript/webdriver/webdriver.js`. You can then go ahead and use this file as described in [selenium's wiki](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs).