# "assertEquals is not defined" in WebDriverJS compiled

Tags: javascript, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I've a problem with the webDriverJS library.

I've downloaded the project and built the js file "webdriver.js" as explained in the [wiki](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#In_the_Browser) and in this post [Selenium WebDriverJS Using in Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870004/selenium-webdriverjs-using-in-browser)

But my problem is I can't use the function "assertEquals". 
I've the error

```
"assertEquals is not defined"
```

Did you know how include the units testing functions in the build file?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

You could get inspiration from the following code that shows an example of WebDriverJS with Jasmine for the assertion: https://github.com/ericminio/webdriverjs-with-jasmine

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I believe the assertEquals function referenced in the WebDriverJS documentation is simply used for demonstration purposes. It isn't part of the webdriverJS library and is something you need to either implement yourself or replace with an assertion library. Hence the error message that it is not defined.

Here is a pretty exhaustive list of assertion libraries you can use: [standalone assertion libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472152/standalone-assertion-libraries)